# How to set the textfield value fixed even after page navigation

Tags: ios

Screen for this issue:

[image: snapshot]

I am saving a value in userdefault(contains date in form of string) for the TextField , When pressing select the page gets navigated when returning to the previous page the date in text field gets erased how can I keep the text field value fixed even after page navigation. Can you please  help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you push a `ViewController` and then pop back, the sate of the parent `ViewController` will be preserved. I cant tell why your code is doing that, but try this:

in `viewWillDisappear`, save the value to `NSUserDefaults`.

in `viewWillAppear`, retrieve the same value from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: In select button i am pushing to another view controller .